# Insulation smell/colour

Tags: insulation

Weird musty smell and greenish colour on Bradford R3.1 Acoustic SoundScreen Insulation. Purchased from FB marketplace, should I be worried about mould?[image]

Comment: Hi Esther, we need a specific question